# Script not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<div class="announcementSlider" id="button">
            <img src="pictures/blank photo.png" class="teacherpic"><br>
            <span>'.$row['LastName'].'</span><br>
            <span>'.$row['Grade'].' - </span>
            <span>'.$row['Section'].'</span>
          </div>';
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "teacherinfo.php";
  };
</script>
```

This code is used to generate div based on the data in mysql. for every row in the database the code will generate a div with a picture, name, grade and section. There is no problem in  the generation of div. The only problem is the script that I used. When ever I click the first div, the script does it work but whenever I click the other divs, the script does not work. Is there something wrong with my code? Can anyone teach me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: **id** attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element ,I think you are using same id for multiple div.Used **class** instead of **id** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementById returns only first matched item.

Use getElementsByClassName instead of getElementByClassId. It will return every matched items. You can use the code below.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("announcementSlider");
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
     a[i].onclick = function () {
         location.href = "teacherinfo.php";
     };
}
```

Comment: I used your code but the problem was not fixed. All the divs were not clickable when I used your code.

Comment: Thanks your code works. There is a new problem that I need to solve.

Comment: how can I use the text of the span in a mysql where clause?

Comment: First, make your divs id unique. (Like text1div, text2div...) Then change the code like this `location.href = "teacherinfo.php?text=" + this.id` and check $_GET['text'] with the php. For example if user clicks second div, it will redirect to 'teacherinfo.php?text=text2div' and $_GET['text'] will be text2div.

Comment: can you show me how? cause Im new at this language.

Comment: how can I implement that in the code above? Because I need the code above to act as the code you send.

Comment: In php side declare a variable before while like `$i = 1;` Then inside while change div's id like `id="text'.$i++.'div"` It will create unique id's. If user clicks second div it will redirect to teacherinfo.php?text=text2div. And `$_GET['text']` will be text2div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379820/using-span-text-in-where-clause-in-php 

go here for detailed question

Comment: In teacherinfo.php you need to check $_GET['text'] variable and just show this one. Show me your query if you don't know how to do.