# Using span text in where clause in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

[image]

This div act as a button. Whenever I click one, the page goes to the page name "teacherinfo.php". The "Sample" text is used as the name of the teacher. The problem is when I click the "Sample2" the Sample text appear on the "teacherinfo.php" page.

[image]

Here is the script for going to "teacherinfo.php":

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<div class="announcementSlider" id="click">
            <img src="pictures/blank photo.png" class="teacherpic"><br>
            <span name="LastName">'.$row['LastName'].'</span><br>
            <span>'.$row['Grade'].' - </span>
            <span>'.$row['Section'].'</span>
          </div>';
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("announcementSlider");
  for (i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function () {
      location.href = "teacherinfo.php";
    };
  }
</script>
```

Code for displaying the text in "teacherinfo.php":

```
<div class="leftForm hide-on-med-and-down">
    <img src="pictures/default-avatar-250x250.png">
    <p class="name"><?php echo $name3; ?></p>
    <p class="section"><?php echo $grade3; ?>-<?php echo $section; ?></p>
  </div>
```

Code for retrieving data in database:

```
$sql3 = mysqli_query($db,"select * from teacherinfo");
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$name3 = $row3['LastName'];
$grade3 = $row3['Grade'];
$section3 = $row3['Section'];
```

I want to use the "'.$row['LastName'].'" as a where clause in mysqli_query($db,"select * from teacherinfo"). How can I do that? or is there another solution to this issue?

Comment: And what do you expect? How can `teacherinfo.php` understand __which__ teacher shoud be shown?

Comment: When I click the "Sample2", I want the text in the "teacherinfo.php" to change to "Sample2" instead of "Sample". "Sample" and "Sample2" act as the teachers name, so if i click either of them the text should be the same in the "teacherinfo.php".

Comment: So __provide__ more data for `teacherinfo.php` so as it can understand what teacher should be selected.

Comment: easier for you to said and do but for me that's not the case. I'm new at this so could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't understand why you use javascript when you can use simple `a` tag with correct `href`:

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<a class="announcementSlider" href="teacherinfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">
            <img src="pictures/blank photo.png" class="teacherpic"><br>
            <span name="LastName">'.$row['LastName'].'</span><br>
            <span>'.$row['Grade'].' - </span>
            <span>'.$row['Section'].'</span>
          </a>';
  }
?>
```

Here, I suppose that every teacher in your mysql-table has some unique `id` field.

On `teacherinfo.php` you access `id` as `$_GET['id']` and create a query like (here I skip security part, **but** `$_GET['id']` can be forged and therefore contain some insecure data, you have to check it):

```
sql3 = mysqli_query($db,"select * from teacherinfo where id = " . $_GET['id']);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$name3 = $row3['LastName'];
$grade3 = $row3['Grade'];
$section3 = $row3['Section'];
```